# Why cannot the print function be returned from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't have any reason why I'd want to do this, but I was still wondering, why do these throw syntax errors:

```
def f():
    return print    # syntaxError: invalid syntax

def f():
    return print()  # syntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But returning other built-in functions is completely ok, like for example these:

```
def f():
    return map    # no errors

def f():
    return len()  # no errors
```

Also I can print any built-in function:

```
>>> print(map)
<built-in function map>

>>> print(set)
<type 'set'>
```

But I cannot print the print function:

```
>>> print(print("test"))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(print("test"))
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're not actually on Python 3. You think you are, but you're not. Get Python 3.

Comment: You're running the code on Python 2, where `print` is a statement rather than a function. You can either upgrade to Python 3, or do `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: `def f():`; `return print()` runs for me with no errors. I'm on Python 3.5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged the question `python-3.x`, but you seem to be running with Python 2.

`print` is a keyword in Python 2.

Comment: Yeah, was accidentally running python2 REPL on my mac...